# Please how do i split this list using the split method in python

Tags: python

Edited

I am trying to scrape **avg_ratings**, **ratings** and **published year** on goodreads so i can put them in a separate list

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/business"

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(response.content, "lxml")


avg_ratings = soup.find_all("span", class_="greyText")
for ratings in avg_ratings:
    print(ratings.get_text().split("-"))
```

Result:

```
['\n                avg rating 4.18 —\n                272,533 ratings  —\n                published 2014\n              ']
['(Goodreads Author)']
['\n                avg rating 4.11 —\n                277,455 ratings  —\n                published 2011\n              ']
['(Goodreads Author)']
['\n                avg rating 4.11 —\n                277,455 ratings  —\n                published 2011\n              ']
['\n                avg rating 4.21 —\n                790,527 ratings  —\n                published 1936\n              '
```

]

Comment: Can you instead tell us what information you are trying to parse and from which page?

Answer (score 1):

your selector need to be more specific or you get unwanted element, use `.tableList .greyText.smallText`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

page = requests.get('https://www.goodreads.com/book/most_read').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

avg_ratings = soup.select(".tableList .greyText.smallText")
for rating in avg_ratings:
    ratings = re.sub(r"\s+", ' ', rating.text) # clean "published\n               2017"
    ratings = [x.strip() for x in ratings.split("—")]
    print(ratings)
```

Comment: Thank you @uingtea, you answered my question well but i still need some clarification. After checking critically inspecting my html i could not find the __Tablelist__ that you used, how do i go about that, then, can you please explain the regex codes you used. Thank you once again

Comment: you can find the class using "view page source" but if different from above please you tell me the URL., and for the regex it replaces multiple newline and space to single space

Comment: view-source:https://www.goodreads.com/book/most_read

Comment: did you search it with the dot `.`?  dot is for class and hash `#` for `id` so `.tableList` is match `class="tableList"`. you can see the class [here](https://postimg.cc/75M5zTm5)